# How to serialize Java Instant type using redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, instant

I'm using spring boot 2.0.3 and
spring-boot-starter-data-redis.
Also using jackson-datatype-jsr310.

I want to store Object into redis.

the object(MyObj):

```
String text;
Instant instant;
```

Here's my code:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    ListOperations<String, MyObj> listOps = redisTemplate.opsForList();

    MyObj o1 = new MyObj();
    o1.setText("foo");
    o1.setInstant(Instant.now());

    listOps.leftPush("foo", o1);

    MyObj o2 = new MyObj();
    o2.setText("bar");
    o2.setInstant(Instant.now());

    listOps.leftPush("foo", o2);

    List<MyObj> list = listOps.range("foo", 0, -1);

    for (MyObj o : list) {
        System.out.println(o.getText());
        System.out.println(o.getInstant());
    }

}
```

in my RedisConfig:

```
redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
```

But when I'm pushing into redis, the error occurs below:

> org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

How to serialize java instant type with Redis?

Any opinion would be appreciated.

Comment: What about creating your own jackson JSONSerializer?

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: Hi Noel, I'm facing same issue. Using my own `ObjectMapper` leads to ClassCastException. Where you able to fix this and how please?

Answer (score 0):

While this is quite an old post, I ran into this problem recently and did the lazy man search and found this before deciding to read the class file. I found that you can easily override the default `ObjectMapper` with a custom one. Use the `setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper)` method on the Serializer to override the default.

```
// Taken from Jackson library
public class Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<T> implements RedisSerializer<T> {

    public static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    private final JavaType javaType;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    // truncated
    
    public void setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

        Assert.notNull(objectMapper, "'objectMapper' must not be null");
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
```

You just need to create an ObjectMapper with the JavaTime.Module registered like below

```
public static ObjectMapper dateMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;

     Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<MyObj> valueSerializer = new 
         Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(MyObj.class);
     valueSerializer.setObjectMapper(dateMapper());
    }
```

`disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)` turns of default behavior.