# Spring Boot with Sping Data Redis cannot start without Sentinel connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

this is my first question so pardon me if the way I phrase the questions still need improvement

I am currently working on a Spring Boot Web Application which uses Redis as a Cache to prevent excessive calls to external APIs. In that sense, Spring is actually good to have but not a necessity.

### The structure of the project is as the follow

1.) A persistence module containings DAO classes that compiles spring-data-redis project and uses RedisTemplate with `@Autowired` annotation

Example RedisDao class(I am not using the exact implementation due to private code reasons):

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate

public AuthInfoDto createAuthInfo(Integer memberId, Integer expiry) {

  //Some method to generate key
  String key = createAuthKey(memberId)

  redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, memberId)

}
```

This project is then built with gradle clean install to generate the jar file to be imported by main project

2.) The main project then compiles the persistence project and I set up configuration in this main project

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class RedisConfigure {

  @Bean
  @Lazy
  public RedisTemplate<String, Integer> redisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Integer> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();

    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory)
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

    return redisTemplate;
   }
}
```

The problem is that; when Sentinel is not available or there's a connection error to Sentinel. The Spring Boot application cannot start

I have tried adding `@Lazy` annotations to all the beans and configuration files including that in the persistence module but its still not working.

Something I notice is that JedisConnectionFactory automatically throws an exception if it cannot detect any Sentinel during startup.

May I know if there are any ways I can prevent spring boot from trying to connect to Sentinel during startup?

Thank you very much

**EDIT**
Here is the error code. As for JedisConnectionFactory Bean; I let spring-data-redis auto configuration handle it for me so i just set the required properties in my application.yml file

```
spring.redis:
  pool:
    max-idle: 10
    min-idle: 5
  sentinel:
    master: redis-cluster
    nodes: sentinelhost1:port1,sentinelhost2:port2,sentinelhost3:port3
```

**ERROR**

```
13:20:01.381 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisReferenceResolver': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [sg/com/rakuten/rewards/rpg/api/domain/configure/RedisCacheConfigure.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConnectionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is redis-cluster master is running...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at sg.com.rakuten.rewards.rpg.api.RPGApiApplication.main(RPGApiApplication.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [sg/com/rakuten/rewards/rpg/api/domain/configure/RedisCacheConfigure.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConnectionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is redis-cluster master is running...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConnectionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is redis-cluster master is running...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is redis-cluster master is running...
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.initSentinels(JedisSentinelPool.java:180)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:95)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createRedisSentinelPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you show the error message and also `jedisConnectionFactory`

Comment: @Deadpool Hi, Thank you for your reply. I added the error message into the question. Thank you

Comment: by error message you to create `jedisConnectionFactory` bean, can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989621/how-to-serialize-java-instant-type-using-redis/51090527#51090527

Comment: use this `new JedisConnectionFactory(RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig)` and for configs ` new RedisClusterConfiguration(Collection<String> clusterNodes)`  cluster configs `clusterHostAndPorts[0] = 127.0.0.1:23679
 clusterHostAndPorts[1] = 127.0.0.1:23680` and let me know still if you have issue

Comment: @Deadpool Thank you for the reply again.

I am not using Redis Cluster so I did a `new JedisConnectionFactory(RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig)` but it is still trying to connect to Sentinel upon startup despite excluding RedisAutoConfiguration.

Comment: use this `JedisConnectionFactory(RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfig)` not `RedisSentinelConfig` , https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.html

Comment: and remove those properties from yml file, try 1st hardcode in code

Comment: Hi @Deadpool Thank you for the follow up

Maybe I will try out Lettuce driver as mp911de mentioned

But I do appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you're seeing comes from `JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet()`. You need to set all Redis-related beans to `@Lazy`, also the connection factory.

You would need to declare your own `JedisConnectionFactory` bean. Alternatively, try using the Lettuce driver as Lettuce attempts to resolve a Redis server rather lazily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Yeah seems like I might try out Lettuce instead. Thank you